# Shortcut non-evaluation for where-excluded union components

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, union

Let us suppose I have 3 tables with identical columns t1,t2,t3, and I run

```
select * 
from
  (
    select 't1' as source, * from t1
    union all
    select 't2' as source, * from t2
    union all
    select 't3' as source, * from t3
  ) view_code 
where source='t3'
```

Is the optimizer smart enough to not even run the select from t1/t2 queries?

Edit: I run the following query:

```
select * from (
select top 1000 '1' as source, map,pda,item from pt
union all
select top 1000 '2' as source, map,pda,item from gt
)t
where source='2'
```

Sure enough, there's only an index scan on gt, and no read operation on pt at all. But I'd like to have a confirmation that it will be this way each time.

Comment: You can try and take a look at the execution plan you get!

Comment: If you have 3 tables with identical columns, you should stop and consider whether your data model is correct. Has some of your data inadvertently been placed in the table *names*?

Comment: I guess in this case, the universe lost :-) (read the quote in my profile)

Comment: @Damien :The selects are simplified to provide a minimal example. In truth, they include about 5 joins on average, creating a denormalized version of our tables so as to be used by a reporting tool.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yep. Check out the execution plan - only t3 is scanned.

```
create table t2 (col1 nvarchar(max), col2 nvarchar(max))
create table t3 (col1 nvarchar(max), col2 nvarchar(max))

insert into t1 values ('¿col1?', '¿col2?')
insert into t2 values ('¿col1?', '¿col2?')
insert into t3 values ('¿col1?', '¿col2?')

select * from ( 
select 't1' as source, * from t1 
union all 
select 't2' as source, * from t2 
union all 
select 't3' as source, * from t3 
)view_code where source='t3'
```

[image]